# Broccoli/Ember-cli: if I'm importing a css file why do I need jquery?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, broccolijs

I'm trying to import a css package and when I run Broccoli (using `ember server`) it's complaining I need jQuery:

```
app.import('bower_components/materialize/dist/materialize.css');
```

Error message:

```
Missing bower packages: 
Package: jquery
  * Specified: ^1.11.1
  * Installed: 2.1.4
```

Note: I'm not planning on using the jQuery components, just the css...can't I just import that without throwing an error?

Comment: Ember depends on jquery. The plan is to eventually remove it but I dont think we're there yet.

Comment: seems like you have version conflict

Comment: I think I need to use Broccoli funnel otherwise it tries to import the entire bower package (including JS I don't want) : http://www.ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies/ ... using funnel lets me just use part of the package as-is (i.e. only the css I want)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I'm having a version conflict because Ember already includes jQuery, so it's already there. But the bower package I want uses another version of Jquery, but I'm not even importing that part of the package (just the css).

Comment: funnel is probably your best bet. Also, have you tried the [ember-cli-materialize](https://github.com/sgasser/ember-cli-materialize) package?

Comment: Okay, did not know ember had a materialize package (explains things). It turns out when I did a bower install of materialize bower changed the version of jQuery I was using...changing it back now since I am only using the css part.

Comment: Damn! Removing the wrong version of jQuery (folder) in bower_components and running bower install seems to have removed materialize (?). Using ```ember install ember-cli-materialize```

Comment: Did ember-cli-materialize work for you? I'm getting a bogus error complaining about missing styles/app.[sass|scss] (which is actually there).